# MySQL restore performance

Tags: mysql

I have what seems to be a slowing MySQL restore, and am looking for some tuning advice (I am a PostgreSQL and SQL Server guy).

The dev server has 48GB of RAM, 8 cores, running Centos 6.2 64-bit and MySQL 5.1.61 (same as production MySQL), and 4 x 7200 RPM SAS drives in software managed RAID-10 / XFS. The only MySQL client process is the restore. The dump was taken with a plain mysqldump of all databases on the production server.

I have applied some of the options from http://derwiki.tumblr.com/post/24490758395/loading-half-a-billion-rows-into-mysql, including setting FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS and UNIQUE_CHECKS to zero. I have included my.cnf below.

Monitoring the restore with mytop and pv (pv backup.sql | mysql -u root -p), it appears that the INSERT INTO statements begin to progressively get slower. qps shown by mytop starts at 3, and drops to 0 at 60% through the dump file. Not sure how accurate mytop is in this case, as 3 inserts (with values) still seems slow. htop shows < 10% CPU utilization on the CPU used by MySQL, and less than 8GB of the 48GB of RAM is being utilized.

Different databases, but similar restore techniques, run about 5-10x faster on the same server using PostgreSQL.

Ideas?

```
[mysqld]
# my.cnf
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0
slow-query-log
long_query_time = 60
log-slow-admin-statements
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql_slow.log
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
max_allowed_packet = 1G
key_buffer_size = 1G
concurrent_insert = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1G
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
```

Comment: To add to the mystery, it appears that restoring a MySQL 5.0 dump to a 5.1 server is part of the problem. Applying the dump to a 5.0 instance takes 40 minutes, compared to the 3.75 hours for 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your innodb indexes are slowing you down. If can change the way you dump the database you can remove all non-primary key indexes load the data then re-add them. Better still order the data to be loaded by the primary key. This is probably too much to ask.

Sounds like you are already aware of these tips:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

The flush to disk operation (`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`) may be happening many times a second. Check your `innodb_log_file_size` * `innodb_log_files_in_group` is sufficient to avoid writing to disk too often.

(I assumed you are using Innodb from your settings)

Comment: Yes, InnoDB. I don't have control over backup method, but I might look to comment out index creation in the dump. I guess a standard dump does not place indexes at the end?

Comment: No it doesn't and from what I recall innodb cannot ignore them. You can use `mysqldump --no-data` for the structure then `mysqldump --no-create-info` for the data. With these it shouldn't be too hard to test. Good luck, hope it helps

Comment: In this database, there are no indexes on other then primary keys (NIH). I will try a few other config options from your suggestions above.